# Dropdown submenu wont close after opening

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

For some reason the dropdown sub-menu wont close after opening on mobile device , in dev tools it works fine but on mobile nothing?

[image]

```
    <nav class="row navbar navbar-default mainmenu onebg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsed-navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs-block" href="#">{{ $global['site_name'] }}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsed-navbar">
            <ul class="nav menu navbar-nav onebg">
                @each('cms::includes.navigationitem', $navigation, 'item')
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and this is the menu items include

```
@if(isset($item['childNavPages']) && count($item['childNavPages']) > 0)
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a class="menuButton dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="{{ $item->uri() }}">
        <span data-acs-boldText="{{ $label }}">{{ $label }}</span>
        {{-- make sure not to format this bit due to inline-block elements space issue--}}
        <div class="visible-xs-block nav-caret"><i class="fas fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div class="hidden-xs nav-caret"><i class="fas fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </a>
    @if(!empty($item['childNavPages']))
        <div class="submenu-wrapper">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-toggle="dropdown">
                @foreach($item['childNavPages'] as $item)
                    @include('cms::includes.navigationitem')
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
@else

<li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a class="menuButton dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="{{ $item->uri() }}">
        <span data-acs-boldText="{{ $label }}">{{ $label }}</span>
    </a>
@endif
</li>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: added code above

Comment: what language is this? I'm not familiar with the `@` syntax.

Comment: application is using Bootstrap & laravel